# How do I get the sum of multiple columns dynamically?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, sum

I have a ton of columns that are created dynamically based on another field, the columns contain 1s in different places based on an ID. I want to sum each column and total it at the bottom.

I have the data in a datatable and I am writing it to an excel file.

I have tried creating an excel range based on rows and then sum that but it does not work.

```
Excel.Range formatRange3 = (Excel.Range)xlsNewSheet.Range[xlsNewSheet.Cells[2, 6], xlsNewSheet.Cells[rw, 6]].Cells; (Range of rows in one column) 

xlsNewSheet.Cells[rw + 1, 6] = "=sum(" + formatRange3 + " )";
```

I get this in the row result `=SUM(System.__ComObject)` so I guess its not possible it to do that.

Is there a way to sum the columns in the datatable and them put the results in a list which I can then write to the excel sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are building up your function as a string and trying to pass in a `Excel.Range` object, which will call `ToString()` that ultimately just gives you the type name (in this case `System.__ComObject`).

You need to get the *address* of the range, and for that you use the range [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) method. For example:

```
xlsNewSheet.Cells[rw + 1, 6] = "=sum(" + formatRange3.Address + " )";
```

And if you are using a modern version of C#, you can use string interpolation to make it more readable:

```
xlsNewSheet.Cells[rw + 1, 6] = $"=sum({formatRange3.Address})";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. I was not able to use 'formateRange3.Address()' but 'formateRange3.Address'